# Create a Summary Form for multiple List items

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation

we are using Sharepoint 2010 Foundation.

We collect our project reportings in one List. Now I would like to create a summary Page / Form, where some parts of the reportings are displayed, e.g. a Page where all project status lights (green / amber / red) are displayed at a glance, rather than clicking through each individual line item / report.

Any idea how to achieve this? any help is much apreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. (Note out of the box this is not possible)

You can easily use SPServices along with jQuery to read the data and modify the list view to show the images.

https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems

http://www.sharepointusecases.com/2014/04/replacing-strings-icons-list-view-jquery-sharepoint-2010/